# How to make a select query for multiple conditions including an all condition?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a query in a stored procedure as shown below

```
select empid 
from tblname 
where place = @place 
and category = @category
```

I want to use this same procedure to get all results for place = 'calicut' ( category can be any). By doing this I can avoid writing seperate `query` if category selected is 'all' in my `dropdownlist`.

Comment: @Praveen Nambiar Thanks for your edit. I was really struggling with my phone to edit it

Comment: good job with the phone...i must say :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to check for NULL -- this assumes you pass NULL when the default 'all' value is selected.  If not, replace NULL with all or whatever value you are passing to the SP:

```
select empid 
from tblname 
where place=@place and 
    (@category IS NULL OR category=@category)
```

This checks the @category parameter -- if it's NULL, then it selects any category.  Else it searches for that specific category.

And if you only care where place = 'calicut', then use this instead:

```
select empid 
from tblname 
where place='calicut' and 
    (@category IS NULL OR category=@category)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT empid 
FROM tblname 
WHERE place = @place 
AND (category = @category OR @category = 'all');
```

Answer (score 1):

One more thing that you can do is initialize the `@category` variable while writing the `stored procedure`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE yourProcName 
   @place VARCHAR(100), 
   @category VARCHAR(50) = ''
AS
BEGIN

  select empid 
  from tblname 
  where place = @place 
  and 
  (@category = '' OR category  = @category)

END
```